# Illustrator add class to svg group

Tags: class, svg, adobe-illustrator

i have searched from hours to find a solution to export a SVG with class on the group element. Is it possible this thing?

I have found a program [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which can edit in XML mode and add the attribute. The problem is that inkscape insert too much garbage code to use in the web.

Can it be done in illustrator or program in which the SVG stays with clean code.

**Edit - 06.12.2015**

For now there is not a good program solution, the best tool to do is [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

For this to work you need to use the ***XML ediotor*** in the program, so it is not very user friendly also it includes too much markup in SVG.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html) is an explanation by Adobe on how to export SVG from Illustrator CC.

they don't mention classes though.

how about ID's? might be equally useful

Illustrator wraps every layer in a `g` element that gets his ID from the layer's name.

you could use it to construct your svg accordingly and get each group of elements with the id you want.

the latest version of AI spits pretty clean code I think.

but you could use an online [tool](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) to optimise it.

Comment: Hi @Uzi i have found some online tools but no one can do this add class to the element. For now it is not a good solution of this problem. The tool which provide something like this is inkscape  https://inkscape.org/en/ .
But for now it use the xml editor and it is not very friendly....  Also it includes too many markup.

Comment: I saw a tweet today from a w3c guy saying **Illustrator CC is capable of exporting SVG with class names.** I haven't tested on AI CC (don't have it) but according to him: you need to apply the same `graphic style` to your elements and that will result with all elements having a class name with the same name of your `graphic style` hope this helps!

Comment: i have try it . It is a option which can save styles and class but not a optional on optional object.